# Xcode code 201 errors running on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, compiler-errors

I changed my app name then try to run app on simulator it shows 201 errors.
But it is working fine on all iPhone devices.

[image]

error show in above image.

below image is my build architecture setting

[image]

Comment: Set **Debug** = **No** under Build Active Architecture Only.

Comment: This is obvious changing appName leads to errors. A better way is to create a new Xcode project with the desired name and add all the files from the current project and the copy appDelegate Code alongWith the certificates.

Comment: i tried but it can't solve my issue and now Xcode show 203 errors. @Poles

Comment: ok, i'll try this. thanks.. @MdIbrahimHassan

Comment: @ArpitJaverya let me know in case of any errors or when it works.

Comment: have you tried deleting and reinstalling app from simulator it will work.

Comment: yes i have tried this also but it can't help in my case. @vaibhav

Comment: @MdIbrahimHassan now its working fine.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer Please accept and Upvote. It would be very kind of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not changed the app name properly, then it would show an error because app name is using throughout your project.

Do one thing, Create a new project and copy all classes and assets to it and built it, check. Might help you.

Comment: @ArpitJaverya : Let me know if you are having any trouble further.

Answer (score 1):

This is obvious changing appName leads to errors. A better way is to create a new Xcode project with the desired name and add all the files from the current project and the copy appDelegate Code alongWith the certificates.